# How to implement Repository pattern efficiently with huge dataset? (Paging, etc.)

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, design-patterns

I'm looking at this example given by Microsoft and I completely get the point of what they're trying to do: http://www.asp.net/mvc/overview/older-versions/getting-started-with-ef-5-using-mvc-4/implementing-the-repository-and-unit-of-work-patterns-in-an-asp-net-mvc-application

My question is: how do you implement this efficiently when doing paging or dealing with huge datasets (millions or more records)? The way I read this code, it ToLists the entire data set every time you call GetStudents from the repo. How do you efficiently implement search, sorting, and paging with a repository (I'm defining efficiently as in the app doesn't have to query ALL rows to do a filter/paging/sorting operation)? In my particular case I'm talking about Entity Framework. I have used IQueryable for efficient queries in the past, but I don't see a way to generate efficient store queries with the repository pattern. Please help!

Comment: They do ToList *after* the filter has been applied to the `IQueryable`, so only the filtered result set is returned from the database.

Comment: You will likely get the best performance by writing stored procedures that are custom tuned to filter/page your data sets in the database.  You can still use the repository pattern, its just that you won't be using EF to auto generate the database calls.

Comment: @GertArnold sometimes the filtered result set is still a million records :-)

Comment: Not with paging, which they also apply.

Comment: @GertArnold what do you mean by paging which they also apply? Am I missing something??

Answer (score 0):

Reading the article you metioned, you should just remove the .ToList(). That will return a IQueryable witch will "Lazy call" your DB.

Just as the example says in:

```
var students = from s in context.Students
               select s;
```

The Point is: when you have large repositories, never Query the whole thing. Always use WHERE criterias. 
Paging the Result might be done in memory (application) or DB. That really depends of your enviroment and needs.

Comment: I am aware that I can return an IQueryable... The problem is that because it is an IQueryable cannot be used with C# functions that perform operations on IQueryable data, for example, String.Join() because that expression cannot be translated to a store expression (i.e., String.Join() is understood by the SQL server). Also, IQueryable technically exposes methods that may not be implemented so it is a leaky abstraction.

Answer (score 0):

If you look towards the bottom of the page you linked to you will see and example with filtering:

```
public virtual IEnumerable<TEntity> Get(
        Expression<Func<TEntity, bool>> filter = null,
        Func<IQueryable<TEntity>, IOrderedQueryable<TEntity>> orderBy = null,
        string includeProperties = "")
```

The Get function applies the filters before materializing the query with toList().  If want to add paging you could add parameters to use with to apply .Top() and .Skip() to your query before materializing.